# move with sign extension in c code

Tags: disassembly, assembly, decompilation, c

I'm quite confused with the

> movsx(move with sign extension)

I'm trying to convert assembly code to C. 
but stuck with movsx part.

[image]

this is the code I got so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    char str[24] = "Aegisone security";//17+1

    char *a;
    a = &str[24]-24;
    char a2 = -*(a+6);


    //str[32] = *(a+6);

    //char str2[4]=a;
    MessageBox(0,"Hello","reversing",0);
    return 0;
}
```

can you help show me some example to usage of movsx thing in c code?
the part I troubled is

```
MOVSX EDX , BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+6]
MOV DWORD PTR SS: [EBP-20],EDX'
```

I need some more detail explanation about this part
my C-code above showing little bit different

```
MOVESX EDX,BYTE PTR DS:[ECX+6]
NEG EDX
MOV BYTE PTR SS:[EBP-20],DL
```

Comment: guys, always it is I found answer myself after 30 minutes I asked a question. change char a2 = -*(a+6) to   int a2 = *(a+6)

Answer (score 1):

The C compiler handles sign extension automatically for signed variables when they're converted into bigger/wider signed variables. However, you defined that variable as a `char` which the standard does not enforce sign-ness for, so the compiler is not obligated to sign-extend that variable assignment.

But the most important part is that only when you replaced the `char` with an `int` you created a variable 4 bytes long that could actually be sign extended.

Last but not least, removing the minus mark obviously removed the `NEG EDX` instruction.

If you didn't, looks like you still need to change the assignment line (`str[32] = *(a+6);`) to treat the destination as a dword sized array, because you're interested in assigning the entire dword. Your code will still have `MOV BYTE PTR SS:[EBP-20],DL` instead of `MOV DWORD PTR SS: [EBP-20],EDX` unless you have something like `(int*)str[8] = *(a+6);`

I replaced the 32 with an 8 because we're indexing 4-byte long array instead of a single byte long array.